# Azure App Service (WebSite) outbound ports

Tags: azure, cloud

Does the outbound ports closed by default in Azure AppServices(website)?

I am trying to stream the log directory from the APPService to my log aggregator (Logstash), it works fine locally but in azure, it is completely silent. Usually, that is NetworkSecurityGroup configuration in case of VM but in APP services I couldn't find the equivalent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in outbound ports as I thought before. The problem was in the Serilog network sinks (https://github.com/pauldambra/Serilog.Sinks.Network) it can't open a socket in Azure APPservices. I have communicated the problem and the fix with the repo owner and it will be fixed in the next release of Serilog.sinks.network

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do with web app logs are logging to file system (inside the app service instance), or to blob storage. There's no component that lets you ship them to directly to logstash. You have various options of getting your logs from blob storage to logstash, but that's outside the scope of this question I guess.